# Filter conditions based on a list of column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Problem:** Suppose I have the following `data.table` object. I want to apply the following filter condition:

`(CMT_1 != "") | (CMT_2 != "") | (CMT_3 != "")`

As there can be more `CMT_*` and I do not know them a-prioi I want to make this condition flexible (depending on how many `CMT_*` columns I have). Any suggestions how to write this nicely?

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  CMT_1 = 1:3,
  CMT_2 = 4:6,
  CMT_4 = 8:10,
  remainder1 = 12:14,
  remainder2 = 15:17
)

cmts <- names(dt)[startsWith(names(dt), "CMT_")]

## filter condition which I want to make flexible
dt[(CMT_1 != "") | (CMT_2 != "") | (CMT_3 != ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using `rowSums` and `.I` to extract those rows before subsetting:

```
cmts <- grep("^CMT_", names(dt), value=TRUE)
dt[dt[, .I[rowSums(.SD!="") > 1L], .SDcols=cmts]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the condition programmatically, then evaluate it:

```
cols = grep('^CMT_', names(dt), value = TRUE)
cond = Reduce(
  function(x, y) call('|', x, y), 
  lapply(cols, function(col) call('nzchar', as.name(col)))
)
dt[eval(cond)]
```

building an expression with `call` and `name` can take some getting used to, it might be easier to use `str2lang` more directly here:

```
cond = str2lang(
  paste(sprintf('nzchar(%s)', cols), collapse = ' | ')
)
cond
# nzchar(CMT_1) | nzchar(CMT_2) | nzchar(CMT_4)
```

Or you can evaluate the columns one by one and `Reduce` using `|` alone:

```
Reduce(
  '|', 
  lapply(cols, function(col) nzchar(dt[[col]]))
)
```

The disadvantage of the `rowSums` approach is matrix conversion -- your whole table has to be converted to matrix first. `nzchar` is also a faster version of `x != ''`.